# How do GitHub and BitBucket parse the git repositories that they host?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Once I push to GitHub / BitBucket, how do they know to parse the git repository? Is it some sort of hook? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub (a Ruby on Rails app) uses [Grit](http://grit.rubyforge.org) (a Ruby library for git) to read and write git repositories on its servers. When someone views a repository, GitHub uses Grit to read the repository if it hasn't been cached, or it uses data from its cache if the repository has been cached.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about bitbucket , but github uses grit http://grit.rubyforge.org/

Comment: How, specifically? Do they poll every git repository every second or are they pinged somehow?

Comment: @Shamoon you know what is git hooks?